# Fatal Error: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted: on Windows 10

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I have installed Postgres v9.6.22 on Windows 10, but when I try to run pgAdmin4, I get the error

**Fatal Error: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted**

[image]

The complete Error Log is

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\kunal.sharma\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\kunal.sharma\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_13124_AXKZZMOOPTLLWRSN
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: DESKTOP-US1VJQM
  - ComSpec: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
  - DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  - FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING: Internet Explorer
  - FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING: Default
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\kunal.sharma
  - JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2+8
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\kunal.sharma\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\DESKTOP-US1VJQM
  - M2_HOME: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3
  - MAVEN_HOME: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 8
  - OneDrive: C:\Users\kunal.sharma\OneDrive
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2+8\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin;;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\kunal.sharma\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: b0138337-8f64-40a9-916f-88440672a12f
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 50822
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 8e0c
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SESSIONNAME: Console
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\WINDOWS
  - TEMP: C:\Users\KUNAL~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\KUNAL~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDOMAIN: DESKTOP-US1VJQM
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: DESKTOP-US1VJQM
  - USERNAME: kunal.sharma
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\kunal.sharma
  - windir: C:\WINDOWS
  - ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN: 1
--------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 349, in create_app
    if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
    return version.value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I know this question has been asked earlier, but I have tried all solutions provided in the answers, but could not get Postgres Server up and running.

Comment: I solved this problem by uninstalling the 64 bit variant and installing the 32 bit variant. Plus I tried again with 64 bit and it started working fine. Still, not sure what the issue was, but this solution worked